# Center a dynamic number of col divs inside a row in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to center a dynamic number of col items in a row in bootstrap. I have tried to find a way of doing this with Bootstrap but it appears to be completely missing.

As people who use bootstrap will know - the cols move over to the far left. You can put a dynamic number of col items into a row - it does not need to add up to 12 (so please don't suggest that it does). This is important if you are going to array out a list of items dynamically. You can have as many or as few cols in a row as you want.

All I wish to do is make sure that - regardless of how many items there are in the row - they sit in the center of the window. They will all be something like: class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6". Example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Something here 1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Something here 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Something here 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There could be 1, 2, 3 or however many. I do not know because it will be how ever many items there are in the list being arrayed out by the server. Either way I need that whole row, regardless of how many panels are in it, to be centered.

I am aware that I could program the divs using server side code in the view but that would get pretty complicated. There must be some way to achieve this in Bootstrap! I just have not found it. I have read a huge amount of SO answers but none of them relate to what I wish to do. I do not know why it does not let you simply put the row in the center - very frustrating.

I just want to center the row cols.

Comment: offset is not a solution for you ?

Comment: @moped- I thought offset was a fixed quantity. Are you suggesting that I do this server side? That was what I was trying to avoid - I believe it can get quite complicated so I would rather see if there is a way to simply center the whole row.

Comment: @moped - I am not suggesting that I would not do that if I had to but it would involve counting out a number of items like a maximum of 4 and then creating a CSS class string depending on how many items have been received. If it is less than 4 then modify the class accordingly. Even then - if you have col-sm-3 then you have to use offset-1 which is not perfect center (I guess it would not look that bad though). It is a bit of a lot of complexity though for something that should be relatively simple to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use centered class on the row and use following css working fiddle attached.

```
.centered {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 0;
}
.centered > div {
   float: none;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: left;
   font-size: 13px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ug4fzcjd/64/

Comment: That is precisely what I wanted! I was about to say how simple it was but it appears that some of it is actually not quite so simple - for example the text sizing. If you try and take any of it out then the text disappears. CSS is obviously still not one of my strong points.